# scroll down the website until the element is found

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

so I've been trying to scroll down on a page until it finds the element I first tried with send keys End method which didn't really work most of the time it would scroll then find and click it (ones it was found)but it would click on some other element because it wasn't  done scrolling.

Next, I tried with Javascript Executor Scroll Into View which was almost perfect for me but it only would scroll down and click right away because the web element was already within in the web browser frame (web browser loaded page and the element was in the frame for the javascript code). i.e The Javascript Executor Scroll Into View would scroll down (without needing sendkeys method) into view that is within the frame (but I need it to scroll down until it would be visible because the website I try on has the element way down the website).

Comment: [Java != JavaScript](http://javascriptisnotjava.com).

Comment: I use Java and javascriptexecutor 
 together. https://chercher.tech/java/javascript-executor-selenium-webdriver